# HTC Tilt 2 -- possible to get Android on it?

Tags: windows-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

One of my friends recently got an HTC Touch Pro 2(US Cellular) and I really like it. It has Windows Mobile on it, but somehow he downloaded a special program to his SD card so that he runs some Windows program and it will boot Android. To get back to factory settings, he just has to turn the phone off and on.

I looked for a similar phone for my carrier(AT&T) and the closest thing to it is the HTC Tilt 2. I'm aware of some of the changes including different keyboard and no 3.5mm jack. Is it crippled in anyway which would prevent me from doing the same thing my friend did though? Also would it void the warranty or anything like that? Also, one last question. When running Android like that do you have "root" capabilities? Like can I install unofficial applications and/or get to a root terminal?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, however as you mentioned it is not completely compatible yet. Some hardware pieces like the camera (and I think speakerphone) will not work for the ATT T2.

Check out the [XDA-Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), specifically rhodium (what our phones are) for more info on the Android developement & cooked winmo ROMs.I don't recall of the top of my head if you need to run Hard-SPL or not to boot into Android off the card of or not, but if you do need to, that'll void the warranty.

Although, in my opinion it's worth it to at least go with a cooked Winmo ROM or Android... even if it voids the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need HardSPL, as you cannot flash Android yet. It just boots from WinMo via Haret, and after a reboot WinMo returns. You might want to backup your SD card contents just in case.

There is work underway in the flashing area, so we can replace WinMo completely and get a nice performance boost to boot. I already have it on the Kaiser and love it, but with the newer MSM based phones it is not there yet (actually AFAICT the problem isn't the flashing itself but initializing the hardware without the help of WinMo).