# can i install windows phone 7 on HTC desire?

Tags: htc-desire, updates

I own a android phone, desire . I wish to install windows phone 7 on it .
 Can I do so ? and if the answer is yes, how ? 
Thanks

Comment: If you had a Desire Z it would be easier since the reverse is quite doable: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device.  That said, I think this is off-topic since you're asking about WP7 and not Android. We can't help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you can't. Android phones are a bit "blocked" for other OSes to be run and installed on the device... By the way the first approach for this can be found at [HD2 ToolBox and Hot Bootloader](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/hd2-toolbox-and-hot-bootloader/), which may help developers to build boot some other OSes on top of Android.

Different from the Windows Mobile era, that for example my [HTC Touch Pro2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=479) can run [Android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=951962)(fully featured) and [Ubuntu](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=640785)(with some restrictions), not to mention al those OSes that have been ported to the [HTC Leo(HD2)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=531).

Comment: i saw that you can install windows 95 on Desire. Why is WP7 so different ?

Comment: You can install Win95 on a x86 emulator for Android. That's the difference...