# Installing Android on a ARM tablet

Tags: installation, arm-processors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have a [Toshiba Journ.e Touch](http://www.toshibatouch.eu/journe_touch_wince/) (ARM processor) with Win CE on it.
I want to replace it with Android, but I faced a lot of problems.
First of all, I'm totally new to the Android world, so I'm not even sure it is possible to do something like this.
Second I came across a lot of distributions, mod's and other stuff, that I'm not sure which is the best choice.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: It's not that easy to port android on a tablet. Android is able to run on ARM architectures but there is a lot of modification work that needs be done to have a usable port on a particular device. You have to start from scratch if there isn't already a port. IMHO this is out of the scope and too localized for Android - Stackexchange. Maybe if you rephrase the question so that it reads something like: How can I find out if Android runs on my ARM tablet?

Comment: try to find out if some other linux runs on it if so you could use the kernel precompiled kernel

Comment: this one cold also be helpfull http://www.androidonhtc.com/wiki/Installing_Android