# Can we install Android 2.3 on Samsung Wave Y GT-S5380K

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have a samsung smartphone Wave Y GT-S5380K with Bada 2.0 OS installed. Can one install android OS on this Phone ? If yes then how ?