# Android HTC Touch2/Mega

Tags: htc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Language Turkish.

Merhaba ;

Benim HTC touch 2 bir telefonum var.Çok uzun süredir araştırma yapıyorum fakat bir türlü android yükleyemedim.Android yüklemek acaba mümkün mü?Bu konuda bilgi veriseniz çok sevinirim.

Teşekkür ederim...

---

**Google Translate:**

Hello;

I have a phone in my HTC touch 2. A kind of research I'm doing for so long now, but could not load android. Is it possible to install Android wonder? Information on this subject I would be glad veriseniz.

Thank you ...

Comment: Hello Nerkek! Questions on Android-SE are expected to be in English. Please try to reformulate your question in English, use an online translator if necessary. We'll try to edit it for grammar and spelling if there are some mistakes.

Comment: I've tried to translate the question... I think he is trying to install Android on a Windows Mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

If the translation is correct, it looks like you are trying to install Android OS on a Windows Mobile phone?

There appears to be a decent guide about this [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20703/run-android-on-your-windows-mobile-phone/). It wildly varies by which device you have.

Comment: Or here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device

Comment: @Chahk that's a better question, I'll mark this one as duplicate of it