# Install android on Nokia

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I would install Android (no matter the version) on my Nokia 5800 Xpress Music. Is It possible? Someone ever tried to do this?

Comment: Hardware sucks.. CPU and RAM aren't enough..

Answer (score 0):

If you are a software developer it may be possible, but for normal people: No...
It's because all the drivers need to be made into something android can understand which is based on Linux...

Why don't you just buy a Android phone? It dosen't have to be that expensive...

Comment: I don't cause I'm a soft developer.
And I'd like to hack my own phone.

Comment: Alright, then you have a lot of work ahead of you.. But you have to design every single driver by your self, and the hardware is as i know it not open source, so you need to make all the work your self...