# Install Android OS To Other Mobile Phones is Possible?

Tags: rom-flashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I want to install android os to other mobile phones like nokia and other non branded china mobiles....!

if it is Possible? or not Possible?

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, not possible.  It would require someone to do a lot of development work.