# Is it possible to install ICS in BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Is it possible to install ICS in Blackberry playbook ?
If so is it possible to revert back to Stock ROM ?