# can i get a froyo 2.2 or other latest android OS which i can put on my samsung omnia i900 with all bluetooth, wifi, cdma and other phone features?

Tags: samsung, windows-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

my phone specifications:

Samsung i900 Omnia

Also known as Samsung WiTu

```
GENERAL 2G Network  GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900
3G Network  HSDPA 2100
Announced   2008, June. Released 2008, July
Status  Discontinued
BODY    Dimensions  112 x 56.9 x 12.5 mm
Weight  122 g
DISPLAY Type    TFT resistive touchscreen, 256K colors (65K effective)
Size    240 x 400 pixels, 3.2 inches (~146 ppi pixel density)
    - Optical trackpad
- Handwriting recognition
SOUND   Alert types Vibration; Downloadable polyphonic, MP3 ringtones
Loudspeaker Yes
3.5mm jack  No
MEMORY  Card slot   microSD, up to 16GB (verified)
Internal    8 GB/16 GB storage, 128 MB RAM, 256 MB ROM
DATA    GPRS    Class 12 (4+1/3+2/2+3/1+4 slots), 32 - 48 kbps
EDGE    Class 12
Speed   HSDPA, 7.2 Mbps
WLAN    Wi-Fi 802.11b/g
Bluetooth   Yes, v2.0 with A2DP
USB Yes, v2.0
CAMERA  Primary 5 MP, 2592х1944 pixels, autofocus, LED flash
Features    Geo-tagging, face and smile detection, image stabilization, wide dynamic range
Video   Yes
Secondary   Videocall camera
FEATURES    OS  Microsoft Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional
CPU Marvell PXA312 624 MHz
Sensors Accelerometer
Messaging   SMS (threaded view), EMS, MMS, Email, Instant Messaging
Browser WAP 2.0/xHTML, HTML, RSS feeds
Radio   Stereo FM radio with RDS
GPS Yes, with A-GPS support
Java    Yes, MIDP 2.0
Colors  Modern Black
    - Pocket Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, PDF viewer)
- MP3/AAC/AAC+/WMA/OGG/AMR player
- DivX/XviD/WMV/MP4 player
- TV-out
- Voice memo
BATTERY     Standard battery, Li-Ion 1440 mAh
Stand-by    Up to 500 h (2G) / 450 h (3G)
Talk time   Up to 5 h 50 min (2G) / 6 h 30 min (3G)
MISC    SAR US   0.39 W/kg (head)     0.52 W/kg (body)    
SAR EU   0.67 W/kg (head)    
Price group 
TESTS   Loudspeaker Voice 70dB / Noise 64dB / Ring 75dB
Audio quality   Noise -79.3dB / Crosstalk -78.7dB
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it has been done. You can find the directions [here](https://sites.google.com/site/android22omnia/).

Comment: thanks Michael Hampton but this build does not have any support for wifi, calls, bluetooth, mic and it is very unstable and gets the phone to become very hot. i have already tried it.

Comment: any1 else with a more accurate solution?

Comment: Exactly what is inaccurate about my answer?

Comment: Michael Hampton

i have tried this rom before and it's no good than just to go through menu. no calls, wifi or any other phone features. u said nothing inaccurate. i just need an accurate version of android to to test on my phone.

Comment: That seems to be the only build of Android available for your device. If it doesn't meet your needs, then you should probably get a different phone.

Comment: its ok my friend.........just wondering if some one else was working on android versions with more improvements for this phone.........that is why posted on this website in the first place.