# Is it technically possible to run Android on MS Surface Windows RT tablet?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Is it technically possible to run Android on MS Surface Windows RT tablet?

How would I make a dual boot solution or run Android inside WinRT host OS?
with touch screen and everything working?

Comment: Hi user12363.  We've found this sort of question to be a poor fit for the site, but have gathered a sort of overview into the linked duplicate question (which should cover the basics of feasibility).  If you (or someone else reading this) discovers a guide for the Surface RT, please add it to the answer on that question :)

Answer (score 2):

To the question, is it possible to run Android on MS Surface tablet, the answer is : YES... but it won't be easy ;)

Android is (like) a full linux distribution containing the bootloader, the kernel many usefull stuff (libc, and many libraries) and end user applications (the visible part of the Android iceberg). It is available on many platform (phones, tablets) and not so much architecture (ARM and x86).

If you want to make Android working on the Surface tablet, it would require some programmation skills...the same skills than the CyanogenMod developpers.

1. You'll have to configure/compile the kernel for the Surface hardware (and you'll probably have to code some new drivers for some of the peripherals).
2. Then, you'll have to cross-compile the android distribution for the Surface architecture (probably the easiest part ;) ).
3. And finally you'll have to find the way to "root" the Surface tablet to be able to store on it a new OS (in a short way : hack the tablet).

In conclusion, it is technically possible to run Android on a Surface tablet, but I think it won't be reasonable ;)

Comment: I'M pretty sure it's not this easy. IIRC these things only boot if the OS is certified i.e. no Linux or Android.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik: I had written a post and a comment to this effect, but I discovered that this is no longer an issue. The Linux Foundation has posted a workaround. See http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9232307/Linux_Foundation_floats_Secure_Boot_workaround

Comment: It is as feasible as running android on an iPad. Technically it would be possible, but most of the hardware wont work and it would be a difficult task because of UEFI secure boot.

Comment: @RyanConrad: It might be a pain, but when has that ever stopped the hacker community ;). If the Surface sells well enough, I'm fairly sure someone will port Android to it. Since it's a Tegra 3 device, it should even be possible to pull the driver blobs off an Android tablet with Tegra 3. PS: Looks like a bunch of fairly popular tablets/phones use the exact same SoC, including the Asus Transformer Prime and the HTC One X.