# China copy of Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: installation, samsung-galaxy-note-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

My uncle recently bought a China copy of Samsung Galaxy Note II. It does not have Android. Is there any way to install Android OS on it?

Comment: Most probably not. Only popular models receive aftermarket support from the community and this phone is probably a very *unpopular* model. So I guess your uncle is hosed. It might be possible to find chinese forums with support for this phone; but yeah, they're chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, there is no way you can install Android on it. As the device has a software (from my knowledge of China-copy phones) which is just a copy of Android's UI. Also, the hardware is nowhere near the original device (Note II in this case).

Theoretically, Android can be installed on most phone's hardware. There are mods available for iPhone as well! However, there are no mods available (AFAIK) for China duplicates. And like I already mentioned, the hardware of such devices also not capable of running *"real"* Android OS.

So unfortunately, I don't see a way for you to install Android on this device.

[See this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device) for further information.

Comment: so will it be possible to install play store or any other app store so as to make some use of the phone?

Comment: Play store is again an Android app. So you can't install it on non-Android software (OS). Also there are no developers developing for these devices so no other app store... Best you can try is install java apps (the old .jar / .jad) which worked in old java based phones like Samsung Corby series. But I doubt, even that would work, but you can give it a shot.