# Dual Booting a Windows 8 Tablet/Smartphone with Android OS?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

Is it possible and indeed practical to dual boot a Windows 8 tablet/smartphone with Jelly Bean 4.0 + ? Are there significant restrictions or limitations in doing so? If this is not achieveable as yet - What about running Bluestacks on these devices, just in the same manner that Bluestacks can run Android Apps as an emulator on a Windows PC (if i'm correct)

Comment: This would possibly/probably be considered a dupe of [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6849) There are simply far too many devices out there for us to feasibly cover a question for each, and the vast majority of the time the answer is "nobody has done this yet".

Comment: @eldarerathis - I did look at that answer previously, but found it to be too broad in his initial question. I specifically want to know about a Windows 8 device being able to run android as well

Comment: @eldarerathis - I assumed (rightly or wrongly) that people like XDA Developers and Modders (i'm not sure if that is the correct term) were usually one step ahead of the game

Comment: Secure Boot technology on RT tablets would probably prevent dual-booting. But, it can be by-passed I think.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar ok I will (in response to Android x86 below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, but without support it would be difficult.

Android does not 100% support for all apps on intel/amd processors

As well as this, you would have to write a kernal / kernel object to support the specific hardware of the device.

This can be quite difficult if propriety information is unavailable.

You would be better to ask at http://forum.xda-developers.com and ask if someone has ported Android to your device, or a device you would be wanting to buy.

Comment: @ The Andro Nerd - Your final sentence regarding XDA and porting makes sense to me. I assumed there would be XDA people on this forum who might provide there 2 cents. What about Bluestacks ?

Comment: @Simon am a member of XDA - but I don't make ROM's. Bluestacks won't work on Windows 8 RT - blame windows for this, they don't allow 'desktop' programs running on RT versions of Windows 8.

Comment: Ah Ok fine, there are obviously different divisions/arms to XDA, shame about the Bluestacks

Comment: Very true, and I suppose you could ask them to try and make a Windows 8 RT/Metro version.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: BlueStacks Android App Player Now Has A MS Surface Pro Tablet - Optimized Version**

Bluestacks android emulator has now finally arrived to Windows 8 (no RT Version currently available), and works like an absolute charm on Windows 8 PCs, notebooks and ultrabooks alike.

BlueStacks for Windows 8 supports an elegant interface and runs in full screen mode by default. The application is also fully optimized for the 1920 x 1080 HD display of Surface Pro.

BlueStacks for Windows 8 is perhaps the most interesting application to hit the OS so far. It’s a significant boost to the otherwise lukewarm offerings of Windows Store. BlueStacks works on all variants of Windows 8, but not on Windows RT. Testing was carried out on Windows 8 Pro 64-bit.

http://www.bluestacks.com/

The above extract was taken from an article entitled **"BlueStacks Android App Player Now Has A Surface Pro-Optimized Version"**  was written for Addictive Tips by Waqas Ahmed on 13th February 2013. For more in depth info:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bluestacks-android-app-player-now-has-a-surface-pro-optimized-version/

Comment: @GAThrawn No I'm not the author (the authors name is stated at the bottom). I thought if I just provided the link to the article, someone would have told me that was no good (because links may diasppear) ?

Comment: It's still copyright infringement, even with the link.  You basically have to treat it like a school assignment -- short quotes and summarizing with a reference is OK, as is writing up your own version from the knowledge you've gained, but outright copying is not.  That said I don't believe we take action on this sort of thing unless the copyright owner makes a claim.  CC @GAThrawn

Comment: @MatthewRead Thx for informing, I was unaware.

Comment: @MatthewRead If you like i'll just include the first paragraph & then link to the article ?

Comment: @GAThrawn Have now re-edited answer.

Comment: @Simon looks good, it's actually easier to read and get the important info from it now too.

Comment: @GAThrawn To be honest, I got a little excited, because when Bluestacks initially came out I sent them a few emails asking them to develop a version for the Surface tablet - and now they have and if it really works that well, it should be an excellent choice for a tablet

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of devices aren't capable of supporting both OSes.  However, you can try [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) on non-ARM tablets; I've tried it on my WindPad and it works.  It's just like dual-booting with Linux.

Probably the most significant limitations are that some hardware is unlikely to work, as driver support is not comprehensive.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I was thinking more in terms of if I purchased a Windows Surface tablet, or Nokia Lumia or HTC Windows 8 smartphone. I guess your saying it is not practical at the moment or hasnt been achieved yet ?

Comment: Android x86 wouldn't work on Surface tablet..

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar - Sachin Android x86 is the platform for ICS, Jelly Bean etc ?

Comment: @Simon Unable to understand your question..

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar - What is Android x86 ?

Comment: @Simon Search the web. Its a project which enables Android to run on x86 CPU architecture. Surface tablet doesn't use this architecture, but your PC does.

Comment: @Simon: if you follow the link in my post, it'll take you straight to their site.  As the name implies, it supports regular PC architectures (ie, tablets) as opposed to ARM.