# Can I convert my Samsung Focus - SAMSUNG SGH-i917 to an Android platform?

Tags: samsung

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I have searched more than one site trying to decide how to convert my Samsung Focus to an Android platform. I'm still wondering if such a process can be accomplished.

Comment: So what do those sites say?

Comment: @Sid: When editing "closed as duplicate" question, **don't** remove the system-generated "possible duplicate" text.

Comment: @AlEverett Well, there were no such message when I was editing this.

Comment: @Sid: Gotcha. It must have been closed while you were editing and so your edit overwrote the edit made by the closing process. No harm done.