# Installing Android on Symbian Phone

Tags: system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I want to know if I can install Android on my Symbian phone.

Please provide the link where I can download Android, and install on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to flash Android on a Symbian phone right now.

However, you could make Google apps work on a Symbian phone. [This guide](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/15663_How_to_Use_Google_services_wit.php) can give you an idea how to do it.

Or if it's just the Android theme / look-and-feel you want, you can take a look at SPB Mobile Shell.

**Edit #1:** It's probably possible to port Android to a Symbian phone. But so far, nobody has really taken any interest in it. Take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964606/is-it-posible-to-port-android-for-a-symbian-phone) on porting Android for Symbian. It might give you a better idea.

Comment: Though I am not challenging your answer and in fact I too think so, I am curious to know what is the exact technical stopping factor. As per [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/ARM) post, symbian devices are ARM based.

Comment: @Narayanan See my Edit #1

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe it is currently possible to flash android onto a symbian phone. I will do some research on this matter and see what I can find out.