# How to install Android completely as new to ASUS Eee pad transformer?

Tags: usb, installation, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have ASUS eee pad transformer.

I used OLife to use Ubuntu on it, it worked but it crashed Ubuntu. Now when i boot it always goes to APX mode, so i have black screen only. No Android, No Ubuntu i got. Nothing shows up on the screen. But when i connect the device using USB to my PC i can see its showing

```
Bus 003 Device 077: ID 0955:7820 NVidia Corp.
```

(Which means its in APX mode.)

Now, I dont want to use Ubuntu on it. 
How can using APX mode, completely install the Android as new on the device from my PC?

Is there any OLife like package available to install Android straight quickly on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Comment: @Izzy except that this was originally a n Android device. It's more like "How do I return to the stock image"

Comment: @GAThrawn Ooops... That wasn't clear from the post. And one cannot be familiar with all devices (*/me apologizes*) In this case, rather send the OP to [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access APX Mode, you can restore a stock ROM using [Easy Flasher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688012).

The steps are the following:

1. Check if your Asus Transformer is supported.
2. Download *Easy Flasher*
3. Download the latest stock ROM from Asus website.
4. Copy the update zip to *asusupdate* folder (inside *Easy Flasher* folder).
5. Open *Easy Flasher* and hit *Flash Asus stock zip*

The application will install the stock ROM back to your Transformer, so from there you can root or install a custom ROM without problems.