# How to install Android on the Touch Pad

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, installation

How can I install Android on the TouchPad? Looking for the latest android mod that can run on the TouchPad and support sound.

Comment: Your question is confusing, you have it tagged as 4.1 Jelly Bean... and yet asking for on how to install... Can you please explain/elaborate what is it you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: This would be the HP TouchPad, yes? There is an omnibus question about installing Android on non-android devices here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [detailed installation guide [XDA]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/HP_Touchpad#First-Time_Android_Rom_Installation_Guide);
And an [example android 4.1.2 rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1981627)(I haven't tried it).
You can find multiple threads for the same at the same subforum (can't post >2 links).