# Android on PC: Correct ISO

Tags: android-versions

I've tried doing this before, and I successfully installed Android on my Dell Inspiron 15 [64bit.]  There was one problem though. No video worked. Not on YouTube, not on the Web. Not when downloaded with any video player. Can anyone please verify an Android ISO that works well with videos and everything? I know people do it, but with which version, and what iso?

Comment: Installing Android onto "foreign" hardware is rather beyond the scope of this site. You are not, perhaps, talking about something like [android x86](http://www.android-x86.org)?

Comment: See also: [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6849)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on a reply to my own post, I will answer it saying that user AI E. nailed it. I have already done that, and would love to help other users do the same. I have succesfully installed it on an AMD processor on a Dell Computer -- if anyone needs help like I did, just let me know.