# Installing Android on the Flame device

Tags: hardware, firefox-for-android

I have the latest firefox os device --the flame-- the developer reference device. I was wondering if it is possible to install android on it.

Given that FirefoxOS is built on top of Android kernel and use the same drivers, albeit with different GUI and less buttons. Would that be possible?

This question is very specific to the flame device, so it's different from [other posted questions about generic devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Comment: There is no such thing like an "Android kernel" (Android is built on Linux, so it's a Linux kernel). And put into easy terms, Android is the GUI on top of the Linux kernel, so it's definitely not an Android device, sorry.

Comment: Android's Linux kernel has further architectural changes that are implemented by Google outside the typical Linux kernel development cycle, such as the inclusion of components like Binder, ashmem, pmem, logger, wakelocks, and different out-of-memory (OOM) handling. By saying Android kernel I am referring to all these addons on top of the Linux kernel that makes Android suitable to run on a mobile device. Otherwise I would just run debian on my phone! What I am trying to say is, unlike all these Windows and Symbian phones, FirefoxOS shares most components other than UI with Android.