# Is it possible to install drivers for new hardware in Android OS?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, installation, hardware, usb-drivers

I would like to know if it is possible  to install drivers for new hardware in Android OS. I know that Android images usually come only with the drivers for the particular device they're design for (to save space I guess). I have a Banana Pi M1 Chineese single board computer that runs Android 4.2. When I try to connect an Edimax wifi dongle to it or other generic Bluethooth dongle they don´t work. Does it make sense trying to look for drivers for these devices or is it worthless because if they existed they would already be installed there? This leads me to a broader question. Is it possible to manually install drivers in Android OS or this isn't supported as in for instance Windows or Linux OS?

Comment: I better aswer for my question is also in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device