# Is there currently a method to install Android as the main OS for Lumia 640 LTE?

Tags: rooting, operating-system, windows-mobile

Sorry if this has already been answered. I've scrounged for recent answers about whether it is possible to replace a Lumia 640 Microsoft phone OS with Android, but as far as I can tell it's not yet possible. I figured you guys would have a better idea than myself.

Long and short of my asking is that I bought one, and I just don't like the OS at all. I'm very much a novice with rooting and any sort of software manipulation, so I came here hoping for some good news.

Comment: Not (feasibly) possible... I had a few Lumia 640's and they were decent phones for $30 (the last price AT&T corporate stores had them for), but there is no Android build for them, although it has a SnapDragon 400 processor and 1Gb of RAM, there is no device tree or kernel source, so it is not possible for the average user to accomplish this task.

Comment: See: [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6849/16575) So in short: if someone has ported a ROM, it might be possible. But note that asking for off-site resources (ROMs, apps etc) is off-topic here.